# graphical select box

Tags: css, forms, select

I've been searching for a way to customize a form's select box across browsers.

I have no problem doing this to an input box, but the select box seems to be a little trickier.

Ultimately, I'd like to have the select box transparent via css and add a background image to it's surrounding div similar to the way I've coded my input boxes

```
<div class="contact-input">
 <input type="text" class="contact-text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>

.contact-input{width:247px;height:48px;background:url('../images/contact-inputbg.png') no-repeat;}
.contact-text{width:217px;height:25px;margin:11px 0 0 11px;background:transparent;border:0;font:16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#a3a3a3;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page [Checkboxes, Radio Buttons, Select Lists, Custom HTML Form Elements](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) shows how to use JS and a little CSS to achieve styled `select, checkbox, and radio` fields. Also, the input fields you use do not have to be wrapped in a `<label>` tag, so this works with [FormTools](http://www.formtools.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS only (there are a lot of issues with styling selects, especially it's text color), but with a little help of JS you can change it's appearance: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/cuaC9/

This is a base example, you can upgrade it further to support pressed, focus, changed or any other state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, this would work and I have fried something similar, but in this case, I am running the form through a software called [FormTools](http://www.formtools.org) and formtools will ignore any form fields inside of `<label>` tags.